# where does kali tools goes on?

Tags: 14.04, kali-linux-tools

I installed some of kali tools in ubuntu 14.04. But from dash I cant find it. Tools I remember I installed like sqlmap, runs from terminal. Can this is possible to list all tools somwhere like in real kali linux? Even I used cairo-dock . It has a application menu entry but I cant find anything related there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new items to your list of installed programs manually.

You will have to find out the corresponding terminal command, then add a custom .desktop file to your applications folder. You can find detailed information for doing so in the following post:

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)